# Debugging without reloading large files

Tags: performance, caching, memory, large-data

I have a 10gb text file and my algorithm needs to load all of them into memory (taking 15 mins approx.) and compute. However, the computation part is quite easy and fast, but I need to debug it over and over. Therefore, every time I change my code, I need to reload the large file again.

SO, is there anyway that I can cache this file in memory for a while, and the computation algorithm is able to look that memory?

---

I guess Database is not optional, since then my algorithm would need to query DB a lot. It will be also slow.

Comment: Reader which gets the file, and puts it into shared memory. Data processing code will get access to same shared memory segment

Answer (score 1):

Get a machine with at least 16GB of RAM, then let the OS do the caching.